# how to define custom week range in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

how to define custom week range in Full Calendar. For example currently it is given 7 days week like 'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'. but i want to display 14 days week like 'SunA','MonA','TueA','WedA','ThuA','FriA','SatB','SunB','MonB','TueB','WedB','ThuB','FriB','SatB'.Is there any property by which i can set my week range days 14 without altering FullCalendar.js??

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is now possible with Custom Views: 
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

If you'd like to take one of the existing view types, like "basic" or "agenda", but display it with a custom duration, like 4-days instead of the stock 1-week or 1-day, do something like the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        center: 'month,agendaFourDay' // buttons for switching between views
    },
    views: {
        agendaFourDay: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 4 },
            buttonText: '4 day'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like this is the issue you'd want to follow (not yet implemented):
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=692